# Unavailable algorithm in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

When I try to launch my model (graphical modeler) in QGIS I get this message (in french) :

> Cet algorithme ne peut pas être lancé :-(  Le modèle que vous essayez
> de lancer contient un algorithme qui n'est pas disponible
> :native:countpointsinpolygon

It translates roughly in the fact that the  `:native:countpointsinpolygon`  algorithm can't be used because it's not available.

I guess it is because I changed QGIS version (currently 3.10.13).

How can I convert it/export ? It was quite a big model, and I this feature (counting points in polygons) didn't disappear from QGIS.

Comment: How old is this model? Which version did you create it under?

Comment: What if you try to delete this algorithm from the model in the new QGIS version and than add it again from the algorithm selection section? Is the tool available in standalone processing (from toolbox)?